# How can I emulate button elevation (shadow) in Android API lower than 21?

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, android-elevation

I have this minimal Android Studio project with just a button.
I assign the button a shadow with:

```
android:elevation="3dp"
android:translationZ="3dp"
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

and I see the shadow in Android Studio Design tab. But I also get a warning in the xml editor

> *Atribute ... is only used in API level 21 and higher (current min is 16)*

And indeed, button shadow is displayed only in emulators with `API level 21 or higher`, and it is shown flat, with no shadow at all in emulators with `API level lower than 21`.

So the concrete question is, how can I emulate the shadow effect in `API's lower than 21`.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="2.24">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/my_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:translationZ="5dp"
                android:stateListAnimator="@null"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:text="BUTTON"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

Button showing shadow, in `API 22`:
[image]

Same button not showing shadow, in `API 16`:
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For `Pre-LolliPop` device you have to Create shadow or elevation using drawable file. This way.

Create `drawable` file in your folder like **element_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#BDBDBD"/>
        <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:bottom="2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
        <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Then add the following code to the element to which you want.

```
android:background="@drawable/element_background"
```

Comment: Yes @Ironman, it works.  But it requires a lot of work dealing with button pressed, focusted, etc.  So I'm leaving button appearance as it was intended to be by Google in each API. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you wish, you can try Carbon. It's a library backporting material features back to 2.2. It supports elevation and generated, animated shadows as well.

https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon